# listen for click in skin class

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

In Flex4 I have a ButtonA with SkinClassA and a ButtonB with SkinClassB. Is it possible to listen in SkinClassA for clicks on ButtonB?

```
<Components:IconToggleClass id="ButtonA" skinClass="SkinClassA">
<s:Button id="ButtonB" skinClass="SkinClassB"  click="ButtonB_clickHandler(event)" />

// the SkinClassA class
<s:SparkSkin currentStateChanging="onCurrentStateChanging(event)" 
     added="onAddedHandler(event)" >

<!-- host component -->
<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[  
    [HostComponent("Components.IconToggleClass")]
 ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script >
    <![CDATA[

    import mx.events.StateChangeEvent;

    private function onAddedHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        setIcon("iconDefault");
    }
//I want something like this:
    private function onButtonBClick():void
    {
       //do something
    }

     ]]>

</fx:Script>
```

Comment: Its possible but not advised. Better solution would be to listen for button click on some parent component and then call a method on second button

Comment: yes, but i need to get into the skin to change the second buttons  icon. The icon changes in the skin on stateChange but when I click buttonB, the skin state  of buttonA does not change nor the icon

Comment: I think I found a solution: the "updateComplete" event in the skin.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the click event in the hostcomponent and update the skinstate accordingly.

```
private function onButtonBClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
   beenClicked = true;
   invalidateSkinState();
}

protected override function getCurrentSkinState():String {
   if (beenClicked) 
       return "clicked";
   else
       return super.getCurrentSkinState();
}
```

In your skin you should then implement the state clicked aswell, where you load the 2nd icon.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason invalidateSkinState(); does not seem to have any effect.